# Calculate total price with products, size, and quantity in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript. I'm building a website for a soap company. I need javascript to calculate prices after customers choose the products，size and quantity.
Here is the link:
http://cgi.sice.indiana.edu/~wl15/label.php

I have tried some javascript from this website: http://javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-calculator-script.phtml   but my javascript didn't show up.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h2>Build Your Bodycare</h2>

  <form action="insertlabel.php" id="privtelabel" method="POST">
    Product:
    <select name='product' id='product' onchange="calculateTotal()" required>
      <option value="Bar Soap">Bar Soap($5)</option>
      <option value="Shave Soap">Shave Soap($6)</option>
      <option value="Shampoo Soap">Shampoo Soap($6)</option>
      <option value="Face Soap">Face Soap($7)</option>
      <option value="Spray">Spray($8)</option>
      <option value="Balm">Lip Balm($8)</option>
      <option value="Bath Soaks">Bath Soaks($10)</option>
    </select>

    <br> Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" id='quantity' required><br> Size:
    <select name='size' id='size' onchange="calculateTotal()">
      <option value="Regular Size(3oz)">Regular Size(3oz)</option>
      <option value="4oz">4oz (extra $2)</option>
      <option value="5oz">5oz (extra $3)</option>

    </select>

    <p>(Sizes are only for soaps.)</p>


    Price:
    <br> Base:
    <select name='base'>
      <option value="Dry Skin">Dry Skin</option>
      <option value="Neatural Skin">Neatural Skin</option>
      <option value="Oily Skin">Oily Skin</option>
      <option value="No Base">None</option>
    </select>
    <p>(Base is only for bar soaps and face soaps.)</p>

    Scent:
    <select name='scents[]' multiple="multiple" required>
      <option value="Cedarwood">Cedarwood</option>
      <option value="Citronella">Citronella</option>
      <option value="Clove">Clove</option>
      <option value="Eucalyptus">Eucalyptus</option>
      <option value="Fir Needle">Fir Needle</option>
      <option value="Geranium">Geranium</option>
      <option value="Lavadin">Lavadin</option>
      <option value="Lavender">Lavender</option>
      <option value="Lemongrass">Lemongrass</option>
      <option value="Lime">Lime</option>
      <option value="Patchouli">Patchouli</option>
      <option value="Peppermint">Peppermint</option>
      <option value="Rosemary">Rosemary</option>
      <option value="Spearmint">Spearmint</option>
      <option value="Star Anise">Star Anise</option>
      <option value="Tea Tree">Tea Tree</option>
    </select>
    <p>up to 4</p><br> Ingredients:
    <select name='ingredients[]' multiple="multiple">
      <option value="Shea Butter">Shea Butter</option>
      <option value="Unscented Mango Butter">Unscented Mango Butter</option>
      <option value="Cocoa Butter">Cocoa Butter</option>
      <option value="Fennel">Fennel</option>
      <option value="Cornmeal">Cornmeal</option>
      <option value="Syrian Rue Seeds">Syrian Rue Seeds</option>
      <option value="Rolled Oats">Rolled Oats</option>
      <option value="Colloidal Oats">Colloidal Oats</option>
      <option value="Activated Charcoal">Activated Charcoal</option>
      <option value="Bentonite Clay">Bentonite Clay</option>
      <option value="Spirulina">Spirulina</option>
      <option value="Coconut Milk Powder">Coconut Milk Powder</option>
      <option value="Pumice">Pumice</option>
      <option value="Cardamom Powder">Cardamom Powder</option>
      <option value="None">None</option>
    </select>
    <p>up to 3</p>
    <p>(Ingredients are only for bar soaps, shampoo soaps, and face soaps.)</p>
    <br> Packaging:
    <select name='packaging'>
      <option value="Co-Brand Label">Co-Brand Label</option>
      <option value="Your-Brand Label">Your-Brand Label</option>
      <option value="Your-Brand box">Your-Brand box</option>
    </select>
    <P>Please email us you artwork at info@soapysoapcompany.com.<br> If you need help with artworks, contact us: 8122698812</P>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name" required> Email: <input type="text" name="email" required> Phone: <input type="number" name="phone" required><br> Message: <input type="text" name="message"><br>(For any additional request, please leave us a message)<br><br>


    <input type="submit" value="submit order">
  </form>




<script>
var product_price = [];
product_price['Bar Soap'] = 5;
product_price['Shave Soap'] = 6;
product_price['Shampoo Soap'] = 6;
product_price['Face Soap'] = 7;
product_price['Spray'] = 8;
product_price['Balm'] = 8;
product_price['Bath Soaks'] = 10;

var size_price = [];
size_price['Regular Size(3oz)'] = 0;
size_price['4oz'] = 2;
size_price['5oz'] = 3;

function getProductPrice() {
  var soapProductPrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["privtelabel"];
  var selectedProduct = theForm.elements["product"];
  soapProductPrice = product_price[selectedProduct.value];
  return soapProductPrice;
}

function getSizePrice() {
  var soapSizePrice = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["privtelabel"];
  var selectedSize = theForm.elements["size"];
  soapSizePrice = size_price[selectedSize.value];
}

function getQuantity() {
  var theForm = document.forms["privtelabel"];
  var quantity = theForm.elements["quantity"];
  var howmany = 0;

  if (quantity.value !== "") {
    howmany = parseInt(quantity.value);
  }
  return howmany;
}

function getTotal() {
  var soapPrice = (getProductPrice() + getSizePrice()) * getQuantity();
  var total = document.getElementById('totalPrice');

  document.getElementById('totalPrice').innerHTML = "Total Price for Soap $" + soapPrice;
  total.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect javascript to calculate the total price and show prices on the website. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Leslie. Can you specify exactly what "isn't working" or what you're having trouble with in your example, and perhaps trim some of the content? For example, your PHP just looks like its inserting data into a database - I don't see that it's relevant/necessary to the problem at hand.

Comment: The first thing I notice is that you're calling `calculateTotal()`, but haven't defined that anywhere in your javascript.

Comment: Hey Tyler, My javascript doesn't work, I need the website to show price after choose item, size, and quantity

Comment: I understand that, and we'd like to help, but your question is a bit too broad at the moment. Which portion of your JavaScript isn't working? What research or attempts have you made to solve the issue? The function that you're seemingly having trouble with doesn't exist in your code, so we can't really help you with it at the moment.

Comment: I edit the question to make it more clear. I follow the website  http://javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-calculator-script.phtml to build javascript, but javascript didn't show up. I don't know which part of my javascript doesn't work. I need help with that.

Comment: As I'd mentioned, you have a few `onchange="calculateTotal()"`, but there's no `calculateTotal` function anywhere in your JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slimmed down your code a little bit, but I think it should be enough to get you on your way. You can check the code comments for more details (or leave a comment and i'll respond if something doesn't make sense):

```js
//Store some references to our DOM elements
var productEl = document.querySelector('#product');
var quantityEl = document.querySelector('#quantity');
var sizeEl = document.querySelector('#size');
var totalCostEl = document.querySelector('#totalCost');

//Add the change event handlers on the applicable elements
productEl.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);
quantityEl.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);
sizeEl.addEventListener('change', calculateTotal);

//Store your data in an object literal (essentially creating a map)
var product_price = {}; //Noticed I replaced the [] with {}
product_price['Bar Soap'] = 5;
product_price['Shave Soap'] = 6;
product_price['Shampoo Soap'] = 6;
product_price['Face Soap'] = 7;
product_price['Spray'] = 8;
product_price['Balm'] = 8;
product_price['Bath Soaks'] = 10;

var size_price = {};   //Noticed I replaced the [] with {}
size_price['Regular Size(3oz)'] = 0;
size_price['4oz'] = 2;
size_price['5oz'] = 3;

//Here's our single event handler - called when any of the 3 elements fire a 'change' event
function calculateTotal() {
  //console.log()
  var unitCost = product_price[productEl.value];
  var additionalCost = size_price[sizeEl.value] || 0;
  var qty = quantityEl.value || 0;

  totalCostEl.textContent = `Total cost: $${(unitCost * qty) + additionalCost}`;
}
```

```html
<html>
<script src="label.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
  <h2>Build Your Bodycare</h2>

  <form action="insertlabel.php" id="privtelabel" method="POST">
    Product:
    <select name='product' id='product' required>
      <option value="Bar Soap">Bar Soap($5)</option>
      <option value="Shave Soap">Shave Soap($6)</option>
      <option value="Shampoo Soap">Shampoo Soap($6)</option>
      <option value="Face Soap">Face Soap($7)</option>
      <option value="Spray">Spray($8)</option>
      <option value="Balm">Lip Balm($8)</option>
      <option value="Bath Soaks">Bath Soaks($10)</option>
    </select>

    <br> Quantity: <input type="text" name="quantity" id='quantity' required><br> Size:
    <select name='size' id='size'>
      <option value="Regular Size(3oz)">Regular Size(3oz)</option>
      <option value="4oz">4oz (extra $2)</option>
      <option value="5oz">5oz (extra $3)</option>

    </select>

    <p>(Sizes are only for soaps.)</p>


    Price: <span id="totalCost"></span>

  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey Tom. Please realize that writing custom functionality for someone who hasn't provided any of it on their own, or answering off-topic questions in general, is frowned upon - the suggested action for these answers is actually to downvote them. I won't do that here but please keep this in mind moving forward. We as a community try our best to carefully curate the questions and knowledge repository here on StackOverflow, but answers like this encourage the opposite.

Comment: @TylerRoper - Gotcha - appreciate the comment instead of the straight downvote. I'll leave my answer up as I guess it's kind of pointless to delete now (and MIGHT be able to help OP), but I will heed your advice about answering vague or poor questions in the future.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll try that